# Is there a way to transform PBI dataset data in virtual service?

Tags: powerbi, dataset, dax, powerbi-desktop

I receive on a daily basis data in data hub from a PBI dataset, but I need to do various transformations to create my reports and calculations. As of today I import with DirectQuery this data into PBI desktop, make the transformations and create the measures needed, to then publish the report in PBI service.

The problem is that I can no longer run these activities on PBI desktop because of the volume of data, I have already tried to clear the cache and uncheck the available options to continue running, but always getting the info *"Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: There's not enough memory to complete this operation"*.

Is there a way to import the data from dataset, make the transformations somewhere else and only import this final data to create the PBI report?
Today I connect my report to this dataset and another two dataflows.

PS: I have no autonomy to receive the data in the dataset in the required format and change the source.

Comment: Why are you refreshing in Power BI Desktop, instead of in the Power BI Service?

Comment: Because the transformation done in desktop uses calculated tables and columns, which is not supported by the refresh in PBI service.

Comment: Got it.  Instead of DirectQuery to the Dataset can you use the Analysis Services connector and Import the data from the XMLA endpoint with a DAX query (eg `evaluate SomeTable` )?  Then it will be a normal Import mode Dataset and you can refresh calculated columns and tables in the service.